# Convert DateTime to yyyyMMddHHmm in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

Is something like the below my only option?  I was hoping there was a better, cleaner, way to accomplish this.

This being, my dates need to end up formatted like so --> 201301080105 for 1:05 AM on 1/8/13.

`SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 111), '/','') + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 108), ':',''),0,13) AS 'My Formatted Date'`

Comment: It's usually better to do such formatting in your presentation layer rather than in the database - try to keep datetimes as datetimes for as long as possible.

Answer (score 9):

This has a few fewer pieces of chopping than the original, but I'd stand by my comment that it's better to do this in your presentation layer - or anywhere, really, with general formatting facilities, rather than the DB:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(20),myDate,112) + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(5),myDate,108),':','')
```

Observations: 112 is a better [style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to use for converting the date portion, since it already has no separators. And, if you specify a length for a conversion and the converted string won't fit, then the rest gets discarded. That's how I eliminated the seconds portion from the time, by only allowing space for hours and minutes. But there's no style that doesn't include separators in the time portion.

Comment: I used a variation of your answer and mine original -->`CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 112) + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(5), GETDATE(), 108), ':','') AS 'Process Date Time',`
Feels cleaner this way.
Unfortunately it really makes sense to put it here given circumstances that I doubt anyone cares to hear.  That said, I typically agree with you and thanks for the answer.

Comment: @RefractedPaladin - well, your original used `myDate` rather than `GETDATE()`, so that's what I put in my answer (even though I actually wrote it with `GETDATE()` in that place).

Answer (score 7):

This is YYYYMMDDHHMMSS

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 108), ':','')
```

For YYYYMMDDHHMM

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) + LEFT(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 108), ':',''),4)
```

OR

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) + REPLACE(LEFT(CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME), 5), ':', '')
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I cannot have the SS, that's why I had to do the SUBSTRING()

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2012+ and Azure SQL Database you can use

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss')
```

Though this does not work with Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for format YYYYMMDDHHMISS

```
SELECT replace(replace(replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120),'-',''),' ',''),':','')
```

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery, this will work

```sql
FORMAT_DATETIME("%G%m%d%H%M%S",Datetime)
```

Datetime example: 2022-01-02T23:59:00

Output:

> YYYYMMDDHHMMSS (20220101235900)