# How to convert DateTime to VARCHAR() without dashes and colons

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

I have a column which has data as such: `2014-08-15 15:11:00`

I want to run a select on this column and end up with this: `20140815151100`

Basically `YYYYMMDDhhmmss`.

I tried to do a `CAST()` and `CONVERT()` to `VARCHAR()` and then remove the dashes & colons but when I do that, I end up with this: `Aug 15 2014  3:11PM`

And that's not what I want. Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert DateTime to yyyyMMddHHmm in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209928/convert-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmm-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In `SQL Server 2012` or later you can use the `Format()` function to get this result:

```
Select Format(YourColumn, N'yyyyMMddHHmmss')
```