# How to convert datetime string without delimiters in SQL Server as datetime?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I am looking to convert a string like this: `20160520191959550` - that is actually date-time for `2016-05-20 19:19:59`.

I tried using `CAST as datetime` in a SQL statement, but got this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Here is the SQL:

```
Select Cast(vbon.DATE_INS As datetime) As DINS 
From vbon
```

I routinely use `CAST` on date strings without delimiters and am looking for a similar solution. Is there a simple way to get the job done without reverting to `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `SUBSTRING`?

Comment: input is string or some numeric value?

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience, I omitted to specify I was working with MS-SQL 2008. Thank you all for your prompt response.

Comment: @BernardFaucher answer of Devart and mine will work in SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 5):

Addtional variant to already posted:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, FORMAT(CONVERT(BIGINT, '20160520191959550'),
                                 '####-##-## ##:##:##"."###'))
```

Comment: Interesting solution for 2012+

Comment: yes, only since 2012, but OP has not specified version, so I decided that such variant should be here)

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server 2012 and later, you can use `DATETIMEFROMPARTS`:

```
DECLARE @DateTimeString varchar(19) = '20160520191959550';
SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
      SUBSTRING(@DateTimeString,1,4)
    , SUBSTRING(@DateTimeString,5,2)
    , SUBSTRING(@DateTimeString,7,2)
    , SUBSTRING(@DateTimeString,9,2)
    , SUBSTRING(@DateTimeString,11,2)
    , SUBSTRING(@DateTimeString,13,2)
    , SUBSTRING(@DateTimeString,15,3)
    );
```

In earlier versions, one method is to build a ISO 8601 formatted string and use `CAST` or `CONVERT`:

```
SELECT CAST(
      SUBSTRING(@DateTimeString,1,4)
     + '-' + SUBSTRING(@DateTimeString,5,2)
     + '-' + SUBSTRING(@DateTimeString,7,2)
     + 'T' + SUBSTRING(@DateTimeString,9,2)
     + ':' + SUBSTRING(@DateTimeString,11,2)
     + ':' + SUBSTRING(@DateTimeString,13,2)
     + '.' + SUBSTRING(@DateTimeString,15,3)
    AS datetime2(3));
```

Comment: `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` is also available in SQL Server 2012 :)

Comment: Thanks, @M.Ali.  I have to stop trusting my memory about such things :-)

Comment: @DanGuzman +1 on the solution, despite the OP not looking for substring etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CAST(
    STUFF(
        STUFF(
            STUFF(
                STUFF('20160520191959550', 9, 0, ' ')
            , 12, 0, ':')
        , 15, 0, ':')
    , 18, 0, '.') AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: An explanation would have been good.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.datestringtodatetime
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @d NVARCHAR(max)
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @table TABLE (
        id int,
        [pos] int,
        [sym] char(1)
    )

    DECLARE @output datetime
    --In this table we determine were to put delimeters
    INSERT INTO @table VALUES
    (1, 5,'-'),
    (2, 8,'-'),
    (3, 11,'T'),
    (4, 14,':'),
    (5, 17,':'),
    (6, 20,'.')

    ;WITH cte AS (
        SELECT STUFF(@d,t.[pos],0,t.[sym]) as d_, 1 as l
        FROM @table t
        WHERE t.id = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT STUFF(c1.d_,t.[pos],0,t.[sym]), l+1
        FROM cte c1
        INNER JOIN @table t
            ON t.id = l+1
    )

    SELECT @output = TRY_CAST(d_ as datetime)
    FROM cte
    WHERE l = 6
    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @output

END
GO
```

You can call it like:

```
SELECT [dbo].[datestringtodatetime] ('20160520191959550')
```

Output:

```
2016-05-20 19:19:59.550
```

If you pass it wrong value you will get `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

I think convert would work for you. I can't test right now but I have done what you are looking for with dates. Here is a good article:
http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Comment: Thank you. However, I had seen tthat specific page before posting my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), vbon.DATE_INS, 112) + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, vbon.DATE_INS, 108), ':','')
```

Ref: [Convert DateTime to yyyyMMddHHmm in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209928/convert-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmm-in-t-sql)

Comment: Thank you. However, I was looking to convert a varchar to a date time format, not the other way around.